# What happens when you use a shared variable for a period of time in Thread A, while Thread B might want to access that variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, ros

I'm  trying to implement a joystick control for a robot using ROS.
Therefore i use a class "Joystick" in which i read the Joystick values in a Thread (daemon).

In the main thread i use the maps of values, specificly the values of the Joystick axes, perform a robot operation, and repeat in a loop.

The code for the **Joystick** looks something like this:

```
class Joystick:
# We'll store the states here.
axis_states = {}
button_states = {}

# this will be the joystick later on
jsdev = file

def init(self):
    # do some stuff, trial and error for all the inputs, etc.
    # which will lead to this
    jsdev = open("/dev/input/js$", 'rb')

    # then i start a thread to continuously read the values:
    thread_for_joy_input = Thread(target=self.get_js_values)
    thread_for_joy_input.daemon = True
    thread_for_joy_input.start() 
    pass

def get_js_values():
    while True: 
        evbuf = jsdev.read(8)
        #update axis_states
        #update button_states
        #...
    pass

def print_vals(self, forever = False, timeout = (1 / 60)):
    while True:
        b = "Buttons: "
        for key, val in self.button_states.iteritems():
            if not any(x in key for x in ["unkn", "dpad", "base"]):
                b += "%s:\t %d\t\t" % (key, val)
            pass
        print b
        a = "Axes: "
        for key, val in self.axis_states.iteritems():
            if not any(x in key for x in ["unkn", "mis"]):
                    a += "%s\t %.2f\t\t" % (key, val)
        print a
        curr_time = datetime.now().time()
        print "%d:%d:%d:%d" % (curr_time.hour,curr_time.minute,curr_time.second,curr_time.microsecond)
        if not forever:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(timeout)
    pass
```

In a **rospy node** (basically another python script) i try to use those variables...

```
# this function is called in the main() function of this module
def joy_ctrl():
    global joystick
    connected = joystick.init()
    if connected == -1:
        return

    print "Controlling robot with a PS3 Controller.\nPress R2 for cartesian control or L2 for jointwise control.\nPress \"SELECT\" to abort"
    # variable for switching between cartesian- (0) and jointwise (1) control
    mode = 0

    btn_x_previously = 0
    joint_selector_1 = 0
    joint_selector_2 = joint_selector_1 + 1

    while True:
        j_vals_unmoved = robot_commander.get_current_joint_values()
        xyz_vals_unmoved = robot_commander.get_current_pose().pose.position
        buttons = joystick.button_states
        axes = joystick.axis_states

        if buttons["select"] == 1:
            break

        if mode == 1:
            joy_x, joy_y, joy_z = axes["x"], axes["y"], axes["rz"]
            if any(x > 0.1 or x < -0.1 for x in [joy_x, joy_y, joy_z]) and buttons["R1"] == 1:
                    # this weirds me out. i'll explain why below
                    joystick.print_vals()
                    angle_increments = assign_steps([ joy_y, joy_z], mode, [joint_selector_1,joint_selector_2])
                    move_incremental_jointwise(angle_increments)
                    wait_for_execution_stop(j_vals_unmoved,angle_increments,mode)
                    robot_not_moving = False
                    pass

        #maybe we need a delay, to ensure the robot is standing still when it receives the next instruction?
        pass
    pass
```

When i test the Joystick-Class by itsself everything works fine. I wrote an infinite loop in which i print the values and it looked pretty fast.

### But now to my problem

When i use the Joystick class in a different script, it starts to get *laggy* ...

### Here's what i did:

Started a script in which i only used the Joystick class and printed the values to a terminal.
Started the ros node.
Moved the joystick up and instantly back.

### Here's what happened:

The *move_incremental_jointwise* function got called multiple times...
That was the reason why i put the print function right above it.

I looked at the timestamps and the corresponding values and in both terminals there were different values for the same time...

Any ideas on why this happens, what exactly happens, and how to fix this??? (I hope i provided all required information)

Note: i began learning python couple months ago, so please excuse bad style. Suggestions/Tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: If I have understood you right, you have two differents issues:
- On the first hand, your problem is that joy_crtl() function is called several times each interaction with the PS3 controller. Here I think that you can handle this in your main, checking if joystick values have changed from one to the following loop.
On the other hand, you don't know why there are differents timestamps for same actions. Are this differents times from differents nodes? If yes, are you syncing your nodes? How?

Comment: @CésarHoyos : not quite. 1) The `joy_ctrl()` is called once. But within the `while` loop the values of the joystick don't stay actual. In fact they stay unchanged for  several iterations. This shouldn't be a problem since i lock the robot with the `moving` variable. But even after execution, the values remain unchanged for a while. 2) i don't synchonize. I just printed the joystick values with a timestamp in both nodes and got different values for the same time. I assume using the variable `joystick` in the main Thread prevents the second Thread, which should update the values, from doing so